# Usage of "audacity" in contractual letter

Tags: appropriate

I'm new to the forum and would like to make a query about usage of the word "audacity".

> "In spite of repeated verbal and written instructions,---------- has shown the audacity to submit incomplete documents again"

Will this be appropriate?

Please suggest some alternate words also

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seeks writing advice, which we do not give, and would be quite impossible in this instance anyway, as we have such a limited understanding of the issues to which you refer. If you can edit the question in some way which seeks an understanding of how exactly *audacity* is used, I would be prepared to reverse this action.

Comment: My apologies..Edited as instructed...

Comment: Why do you want to use the term "audacity"? Why not keep it professional and focussed on the problem issue not your ascribed motive. "In spite of repeated verbal and written instructions,---------- has once more submitted incomplete documents" followed by a statement of what you intend to do about it. E.g. Withhold payment until satisfactory paperwork is received.

Comment: A bit OT, but if this is a legal or HR document, "audacity" is more emotionally charged than you would like. " ------- has continued to submit incomplete documents, despite repeated verbal and written instructions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the word "disregard" may be considered.

As per dictionary.com, the word disregard means the following -

disregard
[dis-ri-gahrd]
verb (used with object)
1. to pay no attention to; leave out of consideration; ignore
2. to treat without due regard, respect, or attentiveness; slight:

Answer (score 1):

> **Audacity -** rude or disrespectful behaviour; impudence.

synonyms: impertinence, insolence, presumption, presumptuousness, forwardness, cheek, cheekiness, impoliteness, bad manners, rudeness, effrontery, nerve, gall, brazenness, brashness, shamelessness, pertness, defiance, boldness, temerity. *- google search result*

*Audacity* is an excellent word that would best be used amongst friends or in a legal court. Using *audacity* in correspondence would make you sound arrogant and haughty.

> "Despite repeated requests, the Contractor has disregarded all verbal and written requests and continues to submit incomplete documentation".
>
> "The waiter had the audacity to correct my pronunciation of the French Champagne".

Comment: Could you cite the source you quote for the list of words at the top? Is it a thesaurus?

Answer (score 0):

It is a very strong personal attack against the person who you say submitted incomplete documents. It claims that this was done intentional and with the goal of annoying you. If you want that person to be fired, and if you are willing to accept the risk that instead you will be labelled as a trouble maker, then it is appropriate. You will most definitely destroy any working relationship with that person.